Use output of each run in postman runner to create a csv to be used in a subsequent collection run for another endpoint
am using Runner in postman and trying to execute an endpoint multiple times
https://some.abc.xyz/users   ( POST ) 

The request body is like below :
{
"email": "{{email}}"
}

I am feeding in the email value through a csv file that I feed the runner .
as an example:
email
43mn@email.com
44mn@email.com

This creates a user and for each request returns a response like:
{
    "id": "123"
}

This is all working fine .
However what I want to do next is extract the id for each response and create a second csv file that I need to use for updating a second endpoint via runner
So the csv that I want to create will be like this :
email , userId
43mn@email.com,123
44mn@email.com,456

how can I achieve this in postman ?

Short answer is that you can't.  You have very limited access to the local file system from within the Postman sandbox so it can't write files to save the output.
It doesn't sound like this is needed at all.
You just have both requests within the same collection\folder.
You parse the response from the create request, and save the ID to a variable to be used in the update request.

I think you want to chain up the two requests. As long as what I understood with your question is that you want to call 2nd request based on the response of 1st request.
I would say you can do it through Post-Script code rather than saving to CSV and calling another API from that CSV.
You can use below code in your Request's Script->Post-Response section and it will do the job you want to do.
if (pm.response.code === 200) {
    // Example data structure you receive
    let responseData = pm.response.json();
    var emailId = pm.variables.get("email");
    var userId = responseData.id;

    // Call another API using response of the https://some.abc.xyz/users
    // Lets consider we need to do POST request to sendEmail endpoint
    var sendEmailRequest =
    {
        "EmailId": emailId,
        "UserId": userId,
    };

    pm.sendRequest({
        url: 'https://some.abc.xyz/sendEmail',
        method: 'POST',
        header: 'Content-Type: application/json',
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: sendEmailRequest
        }
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occurred while sending the email');
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Email Sent.');
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}

Also check the screenshot from Postman for the above example:

NOTE: I haven't ran above code but I have similar code in my personal request which is working fine.
